# Return to Previous Page in Java

Tags: jsp

I have encountered problem with return or redirect to previous page.  Here is the project flow.

1. First I have a list of patients with some functionalities like add, view,, update, delete (CRUD).  No issue at this level here is URL:

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/web-patient-history-sb/patient/list
   ```
2. Next I will go further by accessing each patient info via view and the patient id.  Here is the URL

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/web-patient-history-sb/patient/viewPatientInfo?patientId=6
   ```

This patient info will list all medications of the patient, and also there is CRUD on this section.

3. Next further level is accessing to each medication for updating, deleting, or even add new medication (prescription).

For adding and updating a prescription I use a form and here are urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/web-patient-history-sb/patient/addMedicationForm

http://localhost:8080/web-patient-history-sb/patient/updateMedicationForm?prescriptionId=15
```

Here is where I have the issue of returning to the previous section, back to the patient info.  I have a SAVE button and a link "Back to the Patient Info View".  The issue is missing patientId to return to selected patient.  How could I achieve the return so that when I either click the button or the link, it will bring me back to the patient info view.

Comment: Use the history api ``history.pushState({}, ' ', url)`` then when they click on the back button, it takes them back to the previous page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try with browser history to go back to previous page.

```
<script>
function goBack() 
{
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not what I want.